# Snapshot of an WPF Canvas Area using RenderTargetBitmap

Tags: wpf, png, snapshot, rendertargetbitmap

I want to create a Snapshot of the Canvas Area in my Application. I'm using Visual brush to get the Snapshot and saving the same using PngEncoder. But the resulting PNG is just a empty black image. I'm not sure the issue is with the BitmapSource created or the PNGEncoder issue. Here is the code I'm using to obtain the same.

```
public void ConvertToBitmapSource(UIElement element)
{
    var target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(element.RenderSize.Width), (int)(element.RenderSize.Height), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    var brush = new VisualBrush(element);

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen();


    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0),
    new Point(element.RenderSize.Width, element.RenderSize.Height)));

    drawingContext.Close();

    target.Render(visual);

    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    BitmapFrame outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
    encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame);
    using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite("TestImage.png"))
    {
         encoder.Save(file);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure why exactly your code isn't working. This works:

```
public void WriteToPng(UIElement element, string filename)
{
    var rect = new Rect(element.RenderSize);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(element), null, rect);
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(visual);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        encoder.Save(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried all the ways and all I get is just a black image. I don't get where I'm going wrong @Clemens

Comment: You might call [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) on the element before calling Render.

Comment: Or [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx).

Comment: Sorry Clemens. Your answer was right. But I was loading the UIElement wrongly which was the error.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you both for the question and the answer.

For the benefit of the others looking for the same answer

I found that Clemens way leaves a black band in the image with the image shifted  either down or right. As if it was not rendering the element at the correct position in the bitmap.

So I had to use the VisualBrush as Amar suggested.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
    RenderTargetBitmap RenderVisual(UIElement elt)
    {
        PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(elt);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)elt.RenderSize.Width,   
              (int)elt.RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

        VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(elt);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        using (drawingContext)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), 
                  new Point(elt.RenderSize.Width, elt.RenderSize.Height)));
        }
        rtb.Render(drawingVisual);

        return rtb;
    }
```