# How to save image from Canvas control in WinRT 8.1?

Tags: windows-runtime

I want to make an image editing application on WinRT.
For that I created some xaml page for image ediitng.
I placed one Canvas control in Grid of xaml page and performed drawing on it using all Pointer events of WinRT.
But I am not able to save this Canvas into image.
I tried RenderTargetBitmap to render the Canvas but not worked.
please help me with some sample code for How to save image from Canvas control in WinRT 8.1?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and tell us what the error is that you receive.

Comment: I think this is answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118003/snapshot-of-an-wpf-canvas-area-using-rendertargetbitmap