# RenderTargetBitmap renders a canvas wrong

Tags: wpf, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to save the content of a WPF Canvas in an image with the code:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(canvas.RenderSize);
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
                                                        (int)rect.Bottom, 
                                                        96d, 
                                                        96d, 
                                                        PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(canvas);
BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

pngEncoder.Save(ms);
ms.Close();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("D://logo.png", ms.ToArray());
```

The canvas has a default horizontal alignment of 'Center' and it seems like this is an issue as the rendered image is actually the size of the canvas but includes the blank left margin, only showing part of the actual canvas content. But the blank space isn't even part of the canvas itself.

I tried to wrap the canvas in a grid and put it in a center column but it still renders the blank space from the left. If I align the image left horizontally it indeed renders the whole canvas, but I kind of need it to be centered. Is there any way I can modify the code to only include the canvas content and not the margin?

Comment: You may use a VisualBrush, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496544/1136211

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.