# RenderTargetBitmap renders whole screen instead of Visual only

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to save a circle as png.

This is the code is use:

```
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Width, (int)Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(kreis);

        PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

        if (File.Exists(dateipfad + textBox.Text + ".png"))
            File.Delete(dateipfad + textBox.Text + ".png");

        using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(dateipfad + textBox.Text + ".png"))
        {
            pngImage.Save(fileStream);
        }
```

however it saves always a 525x350 png file (with the circle).

What i want, is that the size of the png file is the same size than the circle.

But when i change `Width` and `Height` to `Kreis.Width` and `Kreis.Height`

> by the way: "Kreis" is german for "circle"

then the image has the correct size, but doesn't contain the circle in it, because the circle is on the right side of the application. And it just makes a screen from the left side.

Is it possible to not only set Width and Height for the RenderTargetBitmap but somehow also set the startX and startY?

Edit:

this is the XAML of the circle:

```
       <Ellipse x:Name="kreis" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" Margin="0" Stroke="#FF8F8FF9" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" Fill="#FF5555D1" StrokeThickness="2"/>
```

This is the image i recieve:

(if you click on the image, you can see that it contains not only the circle. What i would need is that the image contains the circle only, so the width/height of the image is the width/height of the circle.

[image]

Comment: Does the circle have a RenderTransform or LayoutTransform? Would help if you showed the xaml in question.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know what RenderTransform or LayoutTransform is. But i added the XAML of the circle.

Comment: As a note, using non-english identifier names in a programming language with english keywords is awkward. You wouldn't have to explain what a Kreis is if you would have called the variable `circle` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the answer of ILIA BROUDNO in this question: [Snapshot of an WPF Canvas Area using RenderTargetBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118003/snapshot-of-an-wpf-canvas-area-using-rendertargetbitmap)

Your XAML shows that the circle is included in a grid, because the attached property Grid.Column is set to 1. This makes me assue that the size of the circle is painted relative to the grid or even to the window.
So creating a VisualBrush from the Kreis-Element and then explicitly painting this VisualBrush on position 0,0 might solve your problem.

Comment: this worked, thanks!