# WPF How to copy a portion of a canvas into an image and overwrite the image file

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

What I'm trying to do:

1. Load images from a number of .png files saved to disk (if the file doesn't exist, create a new image and fill it with a given colour)
2. Add these images to a Canvas (they are the same size as the canvas and are expected to mostly be off screen with a portion overlapping the actual Canvas area)
3. Draw onto the Canvas using lines, ellipses, etc
4. (On save) take the Canvas and convert it to a flat image held in memory (let's call it the CanvasImage)
5. For each image I loaded in step 1, calculate the portion that overlaps the actual Canvas area and copy that portion of the CanvasImage into the appropriate portion of the original image
6. Save the resulting images to disk, overwriting the existing files

I've had different portions of this working at different times, using code I found by searching for how to do each exact step, but never the full process. I'm mostly struggling with steps 4 to 6 as I don't really understand all the different image-related classes, how you convert between them, and which to use at each step in the process. Though I'm also having some issues with step 1, as I need to be able to overwrite the files at the end.

I've read a lot of the related questions (overwriting images, converting a canvas to an image, copying a portion of an image, etc) and tried the solutions (some of which worked in more simple examples), but I'm struggling to put it all together.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. If there's anything you'd like me to elaborate on I'd be happy to, and if you'd like to see some of the code I can share it (I've just tried a lot of different things so I'm not sure how useful it would be)

Comment: You can convert UIElement to image file using RenderTargetBitmap. You can find examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118003/snapshot-of-an-wpf-canvas-area-using-rendertargetbitmap.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to solve the problem. I'll post the code below for each step I had trouble with in case anyone else will find it useful. The code here is slightly modified to suit the general case.

Step 1: Loading an image from the disk that can be overwritten

```
public static System.Windows.Controls.Image LoadImage(string filePath)
{
    var image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Absolute);
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    image.Width = bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
    image.Height = bitmapImage.PixelHeight;

    image.Source = bitmapImage;

    return image;
}
```

Step 4: Convert canvas to a BitmapImage

```
public static BitmapImage Convert(Canvas canvas)
{
    var sizeRender = new Size(canvas.ActualWidth, canvas.ActualHeight);

    var dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(canvas);
        ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), sizeRender));
    }
    
    var renderBitmap =
        new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)canvas.ActualWidth,
        (int)canvas.ActualHeight,
        96d,
        96d,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    renderBitmap.Render(dv);

    BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

    BitmapImage bitmap;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pngEncoder.Save(stream);
        bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Step 5: Copy a portion of an image into a different image

```
public static void SaveImage(Image inputImage, BitmapImage canvasImage, string fileName)
{
    ... Calculate the portion that overlaps (left, top, width, height) ...

    var canvasImageAsBitmap = BitmapConverter.ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap(canvasImage);
    var croppingRectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
    var croppedRegion = canvasImageAsBitmap.Clone(croppingRectangle, canvasImageAsBitmap.PixelFormat);

    var image = BitmapConverter.ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap((BitmapImage)inputImage.Source);
    var bitmap = new Bitmap((int)inputImage.Width, (int)inputImage.Height);

    ... Calculate the position of the cropped image in the input image (xPos, yPos) ...

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        graphics.DrawImage(croppedRegion, xPos, yPos);
        graphics.Flush();
    }

    bitmap.Save(fileName);
}
```

This step relies on the following code to work:

```
public static Bitmap ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);

        return new Bitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Step 6: Overwrite the image file to save in the disk.

This is just the line `bitmap.Save(fileName);` shown in Step 5, which works due to the implementation of Step 1