# WPF RenderTargetBitmap returns a black image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rendering

I have to "export" a UserControl as an image, I've tried to use RenderTargetBitmap, but this outputs a black image. I tried online solution, but I seem to be missing something.
Here is my code:

UserControl usage :

```
<uc:ImageStatusBar x:Name="OverlayPanel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

UserControl code :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageViewer.Controls.ImageStatusBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageViewer.Controls"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:ImageViewer.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="StatusbarGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StatusBar x:Name="LeftSideStaticStatusBar" Grid.Column="0">
            <StatusBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </StatusBar.Background>
            <StatusBarItem x:Name="Logo" Height="42" Width="42" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="6,0,0,0">
                <Image x:Name="LogoImage"></Image>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <StatusBar x:Name="StatusBar" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="6,0,0,0">
            <StatusBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </StatusBar.Background>
            <StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="4 0 4 0">
                        <uc:StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
        </StatusBar>
        <StatusBar x:Name="RightSideStaticStatusBar" Grid.Column="2">
            <StatusBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"></SolidColorBrush>
            </StatusBar.Background>
            <StatusBarItem x:Name="IntensityBarItem" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="128">
                <uc:IntensityBar x:Name="IntensityBarControl" ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem x:Name="ScaleBarItem" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="100">
                <uc:ScaleBar x:Name="ScaleBarControl" ViewModel="{Binding}"></uc:ScaleBar>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code to Generate the image. For now it's a double click on the the actual UC as I yet in the "design" part of the functionality.

```
private void OverlayPanel_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap =
               new RenderTargetBitmap((int)OverlayPanel.ActualWidth,
                   (int)OverlayPanel.ActualHeight,
                96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bitmap.Render(OverlayPanel);

            int width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            int height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
            int componentsPerPixel = 4;
            int totalPixels = width * height;
            int totalBytes = totalPixels * componentsPerPixel;

            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[totalBytes];
            var pixels = new byte[bitmap.PixelWidth * bitmap.PixelHeight];

            bitmap.CopyPixels(rgbValues, bitmap.PixelWidth * bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8, 0);

            using (FileStream stream = File.Create(@"D:\image3.png"))
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.QualityLevel = 90;
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
                encoder.Save(stream);
                // If you want to export the xamDataChart to a PNG
                // instead of JPEG, use this code block:
                // PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                // encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
                // encoder.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

What I am missing here? Is this the proper solution, should I try and focus on creating the image from "scratch" using the text in the component?

Two more things to mention:
uc:IntensityBar <-- it's an other image
uc:ScaleBar <-- is a grid with some lines.

Comment: Even though it is black, is the image3.png file getting saved with the correct resolution size of the `OverlayPanel`? Have you also tried running all the code that is inside of `OverlayPanel_MouseDoubleClick` on the Dispatcher UI thread?

Comment: @TamBui https://imgur.com/a/wbaL6uE check the images. Looks like the image gets the right size, but it's all black.

Comment: You may try an intermediate DrawingVisual as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119523/1136211

Comment: There is also a lot of redundant code in your method that should be removed for clarity.

Comment: @Clemens some of it is my "test code" this not even close to my final code, it's an MVVM project with ReactiveUI, but for topics I am not familiar with I first try to get to a working solution then decide on the design and actual code.

Comment: @Clemens your solution with DrawingVisual works. Feels like the quality is not there, but I think that is an other topic to address. Thank you!