Measuring WPF TextBox gives zero size
I'm trying to calculate the height of an WPF textbox.
The code below does work for TextBlock, but returns a empty size for TextBox.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var block = new TextBlock();
        block.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(block.DesiredSize); // {0,15.96} ok

        var box = new TextBox();
        box.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(box.DesiredSize); // {0,0} why height = 0 ?

Is there a way to find the height of a TextBox without actually displaying it?

Hello, I'm not exactly sure, but could they be overlapping?

Hi Mert, they're not rendered, but you pointed me in the right direction. The TextBox must to belong to the VisualTree to get a valid size.

Great, I'm glad to hear that, I'm glad it helped even a little bit.

You can render a Visual in a RenderTargetBitmap otherwise, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118003/snapshot-of-an-wpf-canvas-area-using-rendertargetbitmap

It should be sufficient to put the TextBox into some Panel:
var grid = new Grid();
var box = new TextBox();
grid.Children.Add(box);
grid.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
Debug.WriteLine(box.DesiredSize);

Output is:
6;17.96


Answering my own question : it looks like the TextBox must belong to the VisualTree to get a valid size.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var box = new TextBox();
        this.Content = box;  // setting a parent
        box.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(box.DesiredSize); // {6,17.96} ok

Do you know if there is a completely off-screen solution?
Thanks.
